# Declare a date to call in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In a Stored Procedure, I intend to Execute the SP but have to give it the parameter date. The Stored Procedure looks like this:

```
[dbo].[ADM_CTM]
```

The parameter is set up like this:

```
@CurDate(smalldatetime, input, Nodefault)
```

In my effort, I did this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[ADM_CTM] @CurDate(20151001)
```

Please correct the Execution statement as necessary.
Thank you

Comment: Use "Exec [dbo].[ADM_CTM] '01-Oct-2015' I think it will help

Comment: Thank you Alex K. Looks like I was overthinking the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC [dbo].[ADM_CTM] @CurDate = '20151001'
```

Although I recommend explicitly specifying the month, so as to not encounter date format issues:

```
EXEC [dbo].[ADM_CTM] @CurDate = '01-OCT-2015'
```

Comment: YYYYMMDD (without time) is not subject to any interpretation probs

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[ADM_CTM] @CurDate = '20151001'
```